# Как передать параметр в функцию сохранения модели в Django?

Tags: python, django

Стоит задача: при условии, что на странице нажата галочка (а она нажата по умолчанию), необходимо выполнить интересующую функцию после сохранения записи в базе данных. Функцию необходимо выполнять после сохранения записи, поскольку она на вход забирает QuerySet с новой записью и влиять на поведение функции нет возможности. Собственно вопрос в том - как передать параметр этой самой галочки в ту часть программы, которая выполняется после сохранения записи.
Было решено подсесть на сигнал post_save, поскольку это даёт возможность выполнять нужную функцию и при создании новой записи в бд и при изменении старой.
Собственно немного кода:

```
class AssetCreateView(CreateModelView):

    @receiver(post_save, sender=models.Asset)
    def asset_post_save(sender, **kwargs):
        print('post save callback')
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            qs = models.Asset.objects.filter(as_macro=kwargs['instance'].as_macro)
            r = request.HttpRequest()
            actions_bulk.fetch_asset_routes_and_merge(request=r, queryset=qs)

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(AssetCreateView, self).get_initial()
        if self.request.POST.has_key("get_as") and self.request.POST["get_as"] == "on":
            print('\n\nhere!\n\n')
        return initial
```

Где:

- `get_as` - параметр, в зависимости от которого должна\не должна выполняться функция `fetch_asset_routes_and_merge`
- `asset_post_save()` - функция выполняемая в момент после сохранения записи в БД

Чего хотелось бы добиться архитектурно:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=models.Asset)
def asset_post_save(sender, **kwargs):
    if get_as == 'on':
        qs = models.Asset.objects.filter(as_macro='some_var')
        r = request.HttpRequest()
        actions_bulk.fetch_asset_routes_and_merge(request=r, queryset=qs)
```

Применяемый стек: Django 1.11, django-material

Answer (score 1):

Вы наследуетесь от CreateModelView, рискну догадаться, что она наследуется от CreateModelMixin, которая наследуется в свою очередь от CreateModelMixin. Сохранение в базе происходит на уровне сериализатора, который в CreateModelMixin вызывается в методе:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()
```

Соответственно необходимо переопределить этот метод:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
        if get_as:
            asset_post_save()
```

Comment: Наследование происходит действительно от CreateModelView, но сам класс наследуется от других, нежели указано у Вас: CreateModelView(MessageUserMixin, ModelViewMixin, generic.CreateView). Собственно Ваш способ к сожалению не сработал.

Comment: Тогда, попробуйте переопределите метод post, который есть у CreateView

Comment: Вы правы! Сработало! Премного благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно подсказали в комментариях необходимо было переопределить метод наследуемого класса. Класс принял вид:

```
class AssetCreateView(CreateModelView):

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(AssetCreateView, self).get_initial()
        if self.request.GET.has_key("as-macro"):
            initial['as_macro'] = self.request.GET["as-macro"]
        return initial

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        res = super(AssetCreateView, self).post(self, request)
        if self.request.POST.get('get_as') == 'on':
            qs = models.Asset.objects.filter(as_macro=self.request.POST.get('as_macro'))
            from django.http import request
            r = request.HttpRequest()
            actions_bulk.fetch_asset_routes_and_merge(request=r, queryset=qs)
        return res
```